# ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error on a network volume

Tags: networking, filesystems, find, ls, file-sharing

I am using the same volume from different Linux and MS-Windows machines:

`/run/user/1001/gvfs/afp-volume:host=...`

(in Windows it is mounted as standard network drive)

It was working ok for some time and recently on Linux machines I started to get errors:

`ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error`

When doing `find` over the drive or `ls -al` in one particular directory and both operations started to get painfully slow even though the files were accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gnome Files I've noticed that this directory contains a few `*zone*` files with long and strange name. The files were not visible in `ls` output and I was not able to delete them using Files window.

I know that when you copy something from Windows local drive to the network one OS copies extended NTFS attributes to the corresponding `*zone*` file.

When I mounted the drive in VirtualBox Windows machine I noticed that the name of the Zone file got strangely changed so it was no longer corresponding to the files contained in the directory. I was able however to move the other files to another directory and delete the mangled directory along with the strange Zone files.

Thus volume structure is cleared-up and it works as expected.

Perhaps this will save someone a few minutes.